# SQL Syntax Error When Adding Convert Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This works

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(DATENAME(DAY, GETDATE()), 3) + '-' +
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()), 3) + ' ' + '-' +
    RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR), 2)
```

This also works

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), GETDATE())
```

But when I combine both then I get an error

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(DATENAME(DAY, GETDATE()), 3) + '-' +
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()), 3) + ' ' + '-' +
    RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR), 2) + ' ' 
    CONVERT(TIME(0), GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question, but your first query is overcomplicated.  I don't understand the date format, but whatever you need, this is a simpler method:

```
SELECT DATENAME(DAY, GETDATE()) + '-' +
       LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()), 3) + ' -' +
       RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()), 2)
```

Notes:

- The `DAY` component is never more than 2 characters, so `LEFT(. . . , 3)` is unnecessary.
- `' ' + '-'` can be simplified to `' -'`.
- You can use `DATENAME()` on the year as well.

Comment: You made it so simple.  Thanks for the short answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - you need to add `+` operator and also `cast` it to `varchar()`

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(Day,GETDATE()),3) + '-' +
LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()),3) + ' ' + '-' +
RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR),2) + ' ' +
cast(convert(time(0),getDate()) as varchar(10))
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine and I will mark your reply as answer.